# ffmpeg subtitles alignment and position

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

I am adding subtitles to a video using:

```
ffmpeg -i "imput.mp4" -lavfi "subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,Fontsize=18'" -crf 1 -c:a copy "output.mp4"
```

Which results in:

[image: No Alignment]

I am repositioning this using *Alignment* :

```
ffmpeg -i "imput.mp4" -lavfi "subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='Alignment=9,OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,Fontsize=18'" -crf 1 -c:a copy "output.mp4"
```

[image: Alignment=9]

But according to the [Line-Alignment ASS Tags](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/) docs, there are only 9 positions. 1: Bottom left, 2: Bottom center, 3: Bottom right, 5: Top left, 6: Top center, 7: Top right, 9: Middle left, 10: Middle center, 11: Middle right

Is there a way to tweak this positioning?

I want the subs to be left-aligned, but lower down. Like this:

[image: result]

Comment: *subs to be left-aligned, but lower down* --> sounds like `Alignment=1`

Comment: Yes, I've experimented with all 9 positions, but when trying to specify the margin it has no effect. It seems the _Alignment_ parameter overrides the _MarginV_: `ffmpeg -i "imput.mp4" -lavfi "subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='Alignment=1,OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,Fontsize=18,MarginV=25'" -crf 1 -c:a copy "output.mp4"`

Comment: -crf
Would please explain it ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out the trick for doing this is to add **Alignment=0**. 
Then you can use **MarginV** and **MarginL** freely:

```
ffmpeg -i "imput.mp4" -lavfi "subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='Alignment=0,OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,Fontsize=18,MarginL=5,MarginV=25'" -crf 1 -c:a copy "output.mp4"
```

Comment: Which values can I put in MarginV and MarginL? Are the numbers in pixels?

Comment: @onenoa wondering the same

Answer (score 22):

I have tested every alignment and made documentation with my design skills.

[image]

Comment: Nice apple.....

Answer (score 2):

in fact you can also put some margin like "MarginV=20" in order to teweak position of subtitles

```
ffmpeg2 -y -i "C:\Users\input.mxf" -pix_fmt yuv422p -vcodec mpeg2video -non_linear_quant 1 -flags +ildct+ilme -top 1 -dc 10 -intra_vlc 1 -qmax 6 -lmin "1*QP2LAMBDA" -vtag xd5c -rc_max_vbv_use 1 -rc_min_vbv_use 1 -g 12 -b:v 50000k -minrate 50000k -maxrate 51000k -bufsize 8000k -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 -vf "subtitles=subtitles_file.mxf_Subtitle.srt:force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,MarginV=20" -acodec copy "output.mxf"
```

Comment: I already tried adding MarginV=25 to my code has no effect:`ffmpeg -i "imput.mp4" -lavfi "subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='Alignment=9,OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,Fontsize=18,MarginV=25'" -crf 1 -c:a copy "output.mp4"` also I tried removing Alignment=9, but it doesn't left-align

Comment: can you try using ```-vf``` flag instead of ```-lavfi``` ?

Comment: thanks, I tried using `-vf` but it had no affect. It seems *Alignment=9* overrides the *MarginV* property. Unless there is some other way to left-align without using the *Alignment* property

Comment: did you try -vf and without Alignment property ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with setting Alignment=0. -lavfi  or -vf makes no difference. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57886939/1954892

Comment: i can not get alignment=6 to work. seems alignment=0 and marginv makes no differnece here either.

Answer (score 2):

I try to small size the text and turn the margin of bottom:
`Alignment=2, Fontsize = 5, MarginV = 1`
It's work for me.
like this way:

```
ffmpeg -i "1.mkv" -lavfi "subtitles=1.srt:force_style='Alignment=2,OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,Fontsize= 12,MarginV=35'" -crf 1 -c:a copy  -vcodec h264_nvenc  "output.mkv"
```

**`-vcodec h264_nvenc` is cuda accelerator.*