# How can I display lots of subtitles at arbitrary positions in a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-subtitles

I am trying to write subtitles and display them at lots of positions throughout a video at arbitrary positions. I have a long list of times and positions to display the text in the video, but I don't know how to encode these times and positions into the subtitles file. A lot of the examples on the web only show how to display a single subtitle, or don't explain the syntax of the subtitles files.

I couldn't find a simple answer to how to do this, so I had to put together a lot of methods, and I'm going to answer my own question.

Answer (score 3):

The main options for doing this are:

- Using a GUI/standalone program (@llogan mentioned [aegisub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aegisub))
- 'drawtext' filter in ffmpeg
- subtitles filter with an SRT file
- subtitles filter with an SSA file
- subtitles filter with an ASS file

I wanted to write my own subtitles in a text file (to make it scriptable), not use a standalone GUI. Some of methods don't allow arbitrary positioning (the subtitle will always be centered at the bottom). Others don't allow loading a long list of subtitles from a file, ie you have to encode them all into the ffmpeg command string, which is unwieldy.

Here's the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) on the subtitles filter, but it doesn't actually explain the syntax of the accompanying files. In fact I found it very difficult to find clear documentation of ANY of the options for subtitles files. I went with ASS because it seemed to work, and I discovered enough templates on the internet that I was able to figure out the most important features by trial and error.

First, create a text file called `desc.ass` that looks like this:

```
[Script Info]
PlayResY: 600
WrapStyle: 1

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, Alignment, MarginL, MarginV
Style: N,Arial,60,&H00FFFF,1,425,550
Style: NE,Arial,60,&H00FFFF,1,650,480
Style: E,Arial,60,&H00FFFF,1,700,250
Style: SE,Arial,60,&H00FFFF,1,600,50
Style: S,Arial,60,&H00FFFF,1,400,0
Style: SW,Arial,60,&H00FFFF,1,150,50
Style: W,Arial,60,&H00FFFF,1,100,250
Style: NW,Arial,60,&H00FFFF,1,150,500

[Events]
Format: Start, End, Style, Text
Dialogue: 00:00:01.00, 00:00:05.00, E, Text to display with the E style
Dialogue: 00:00:05.00, 00:00:05.50, N, Text to display with the N style
```

The actual file has many many more "Dialogue" lines after this, but I truncated for readability.

I don't really understand the `Script Info` section yet. :(

The `V4+ Styles` section allows you to specify an arbitrary number of "Styles", which define color, position, font, and a lot of other things. Each actual subtitle will use one of these styles.

If you have a small number of positions that each subtitle will be displayed in, I think it's easier to define a Style for each position. Because I wanted to display subtitles at one of 8 positions, I defined 8 styles. But you can override the position of any given subtitle (see below). So another option is to use a single Style for everything, and just define the position of each subtitle as necessary.

`PrimaryColour` is a hex color argument (although it seems to be backwards for some reason, so yellow gives you cyan and vice versa).
`Alignment` [refers to the numerical keypad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869367/ffmpeg-subtitles-alignment-and-position), so 1 means lower left and 5 means center.
`MarginL` and `MarginV` allow you to apply horizontal and vertical offsets to the default alignment.

You can specify lots more attributes here just by adding elements to the `Format` line, and then specifying them on each `Style` line. [This page is the most comprehensive documentation I could find](https://fileformats.fandom.com/wiki/SubStation_Alpha#File_specification).

Everybody on the internet copy/pastes the same example text with lots of formats specified (e.g., [here](https://hhsprings.bitbucket.io/docs/programming/examples/ffmpeg/subtitle/ass.html)). [This](https://fileinfo.com/extension/ass) is another, simpler example. Would be great if someone could post clear documentation on what each of these attributes mean!

The `[Events]` section defines the individual subtitles. Here, I'm only specifying the basics: start time, end time, style name, and the text.

You can [override the position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubStation_Alpha) of any given `Dialogue` element by adding the string `{\pos(400,570)}` to the beginning of the `Text` element on that line. (Obviously replace 400, 570 with your desired position.)

You can preview the results of applying these subtitles to a video named `video.mkv` with `ffplay` like this:
`ffplay -i video.mkv -vf "subtitles=desc.ass"`
Some people call this soft-subbing because the video itself isn't being changed, the subtitles are just displayed over it.

If you want to burn the subtitles permanently into the video (sometimes called hard-subbing), you can re-encode like this:
`ffmpeg -i video.mkv -vf "subtitles=desc.ass" video_with_subtitles.mkv`

[Ref for burning subtitles](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo)

Comment: Worth mentioning that aegisub is a GUI program for creating ASS files.